# postgres upsert json props

Tags: postgresql, unique, jsonb, upsert, postgresql-9.6

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm trying to get into the nitty gritty of what I can do in postgres 9.6.1 and this seems like maybe its possible.  So given this table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS live_data;
CREATE TABLE live_data (
rec_id TEXT,
control_data JSONB
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX rec_id_idx ON live_data (rec_id);
```

I want to be able to upsert individual props on the control_data json without having to upsert a whole new json string.

With no rows in that table yet I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO live_data(rec_id, control_data) VALUES ('1', '{"set":{"some_prop": 99}}')
ON CONFLICT (rec_id) DO UPDATE SET control_data->'set'->'some_prop' = 99;
```

FWIW I get this error on that query :

```
syntax error at or near "->"
```

Am I writing that query wrong and/or is what I want to do just not currently possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
INSERT INTO live_data(rec_id, control_data) 
VALUES ('1', '{"set":{"some_prop": 99}}');

INSERT INTO live_data(rec_id, control_data) 
VALUES ('1', '{"set":{"some_prop": 88}}')
ON CONFLICT (rec_id) DO 
UPDATE SET control_data = 
    jsonb_set(live_data.control_data, array['set','some_prop'], '88', true)
RETURNING *;

 rec_id |        control_data        
--------+----------------------------
 1      | {"set": {"some_prop": 88}}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ***json*** column has a value like below,

```
[
   {
      "Code":"xyz",
      "Amount":[
         {
            "Type":"Pay1",
            "Amount":"999",
            "username":"henry"
         },
         {
            "Type":"Pay2",
            "Amount":"499",
            "username":"rohilpatel",
            "Bonus":"100"
         }
      ],
      "Currency":"$"
   }
]
```

**Below sql query will add the key-value pair OR update if exist at specified path. [Upsert will work like this way]**

```
update tableName
SET  columnName = jsonb_set(columnName, '{0,Amount,1,Bonus}', '200')
```